# ssh config file for git on mac timeout

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

I have 2 accounts that I want to use with Github, and I am trying to set up github to work on multiple accounts via ~/.ssh/config by following this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/). I created 2 ssh keys (for example rsa_1 and rsa_2) and set up the ~/.ssh/config file like this:

```
Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User username1
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
        IdentitiesOnly yes

Host work.github.com
        HostName github.com
        User username2
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

then, I set the remote url on the repo I want to use with another account with

```
git remote set-url origin work.github.com:<shared_gitrepo_name>/project.git
```

but when I git push origin, it always times out with

```
ssh: connect to host work.github.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

which makes me think that the config file isn't being referenced. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you connect with `ssh github.com` ?

Comment: yes I can, here is the response for it: ssh -T git@github.com
 You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: So did it work without sudo (as I mentioned in the discussion)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong Username in both cases:

```
Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git <========================== 
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
        IdentitiesOnly yes

Host work.github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git <==========================
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

You always ask for an SSH sesssion to github.com as user "`git`", not user "`usernamex`".
The fact your public key is copied to `username1` or `username2` [SSH profile page](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) will be enough for GitHub to know who you are.

But, as [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) note [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986397/ssh-config-file-for-git-on-mac-timeout/62989224#comment111384564_62986397), a timeout might indicate a network connection issue (like a firewall blocking the outgoing traffic on port 22).
Even if that was working, then the wrong user would fail the ssh call anyway.

Note: as seen in [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49999047#49999047), don't use `sudo`
Using `sudo` means only `/etc/shh/config` will be considered, not `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Could a wrong username be the cause of timeouts? For `ssh phd@github.com` I got
"phd@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).", not a timeout.

Comment: @phd Not sure. What I am sure is: as long as your `User` is not `git`, any ssh call to github won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed the User to git for both instances, but the request is still timing out, I also set up 2 remotes, one with `work.github.com:<shared_gitrepo_name>/project.git` and one with `git@work.github.com<shared_gitrepo_name>/project.git`, but both are timing out still

Comment: @accAscrub So in addition of the user, there must be a network issue.

Comment: Is there any way to test if its a network issue? ssh -T git@github.com works fine for me, does that mean its not a network issue?

Comment: @accAscrub Does `ssh -T github.com` or `ssh -T work.github.com` work? (using only the `Host` entry names, without adding `git@`) Are you pushing with a different user than the one doing the ssh -T test

Comment: @VonC `ssh -T github.com` gives me <computer-user>@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) and `ssh -T work.github.com` times out as before. Do you think maybe the ssh config file isn't working?

Comment: @accAscrub For testing, can you change the `Host github.com` entry to `Host testgh` for instance? Then try again with `ssh -T testgh`: just to check the `~/.ssh/config` is indeed active.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218294/discussion-between-accascrub-and-vonc).